# Windows Application is Crashed due to Multiple ActiveX Objects

Tags: c#, winforms, activex, unmanaged

An ActiveX Control was used in Windows Form Application with sinlge object was shared during the application scope.

The application is updated to have multiple objects of that ActiveX Control in various child forms of application.

After the update, when a child form(with ActiveX object) is opened and then the value of some property is changed in the main form then the application gets crashed.
[image]

The error details  in the event viewer are as follow:
(Faulting module name: ABCCTL.ocx_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4ee8a4ee
Exception code: 0xc0000005

The events viewer shows below details:
[image]

Can anyone help me to catch that exception of unmanaged code in C# or fix the problem without change the ActiveX control.

Comment: There is not much SO can do for you - contact authors of the control to investigate/fix the issue.